# Why don't I see an "edit" link below the post on this page?

Tags: support

This question:
[Can't authorize computer to play iTunes songs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/cant-authorise-computer-to-play-itunes-songs)

could use some editing, but I don't see an "edit" link below the question as I see on other questions.

I tried editing the URL to match the URL I see when editing an article (https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/36760/edit) but I get a "Page Not Found" error for that URL.

What happened with this question? Is it a website error, or am I not allowed to edit it for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was already a pending edit. I have approved it and you should be able to submit your own edit now.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I didn't realize the edit link would be hidden due to pending edits.